# SHA256 of MakeCat in Windows is different than expected SHA256

Tags: windows, winapi

Windows has a tool called [MakeCat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-makecat-to-create-a-catalog-file) which generates a catalog file that contains SHA256 hashes of files on the operating system.

Let's say we take Optane.dll as an example file.

Using the Makecat tool to create a catalog file results in an SHA256 hash of 230EB11F89F6B7B4E6C8E069D6A2A68820E7002625D2DF2F30B80043906433F1.
[image]

However, putting the same file through any online or local file SHA256 calculator results in a different hash - 4C5E4407A6056B60089F8406CA75F230988A2528FA84F7965C5BF6ED883FB79A
[image]

Any ideas how MakeCat is calculating the hash? I believe internally it calls CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle Windows API.

**My aim: Calculate this Makecat style hash for some files in a Linux environment** and store it in a CDF file so I can use it later.

Comment: No, the `230EB1...` hash is indeed pertaining to the individually cataloged file - but it's also not a file hash, it's an _authenticode signature_, which is calculated over a CMS blob that contains the file contents + additional attributes - it's not comparable to a hash of the raw file on disk

Comment: Any ideas what additional attributes they use? 

I wanted to calculate these types of hashes on a Linux machine and put them in a CDF file for later processing. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: I don't know the exact format, but [this project](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode) might be of interest (from my limited testing I could only get it to extract embedded signatures though, I had no success with catalog files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the hash is from carefully selected portions of files to avoid some inconsistent hashing.

Attributes, optional data, and other potentially machine-specific data are ignored.

[Here's the document from 2008 by Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/authenticode_pe.docx) that details the whole structure of Portable Executable (PE) files and how data is stored, signed, and hashed.

(**Warning: link directly downloads the word document from MS servers**)

This hashing mechanism has already been implemented in the [LIEF Project](https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF) and hence we can get the same SHA256 hash by doing:

```
import lief

binary = lief.parse("Optane.dll") # Any file you wish to hash
sha256_hex_string = binary.authentihash_sha256.hex()
```

This hash will be the same as the one returned by CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle2.